# Layout override for repeatable subform custom field

Tags: custom-field, template-override, subform, repeatable-field, jlayout

I am trying to apply custom field override to my article and some of the fields I am trying to access are inside repeatable and non-repeatable subforms. Please how do I access and display subform repeatable fields?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 3):

This helped me to solve my problem...

```
<?php $fieldX = json_decode($this->item->jcfields[X]->rawvalue, true); ?>
```

where X is the Id of the subform native field
A, B, C is the respective Id of the custom fields inside of the subform.

NB: this solution only works for repeatable subforms.
For subforms that are not repeatable, there is no need to loop through the associative array.